# Admin User create event

Tags: admin, magento-1.8, user-roles, user

I am working on a new project. I am facing a problem where I need to save the details when an admin user is created. I am planning to use an observer to catch the event. I need to know that is there any event in magento defined for getting the admin user creation.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use `admin_user_save_after`.
In your observer you can then retrieve the user like this:

```
public function doSomething($observer){
    $adminUser = $observer->getEvent()->getObject();
    //do something with admin user
}
```

Keep in mind that this event is dispatched even when an existing user changes his password.
To identify if the user is new, you can check :

```
$adminUser->getOrigData('user_id');
```

If the code above returns `null`  then is a new admin.